# Convert Time format(hh:mm) to Decimal format

Tags: db2

I am getting hours by subtracting time fields in the format hh:mm(00:21)
by using this 
rtrim(char(TIMESTAMPDIFF(8,char(LABTRANS.finishtime - LABTRANS.starttime)))) || ':'|| rtrim(char(mod(int(TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,char(LABTRANS.finishtime - LABTRANS.starttime))),60))) as total_time,
), but i have to show in decimal value ( 0.3500 ). How can i achieve  it.

see my sample table :
-->create table labtrans(starttime TIME,finishtime TIME)
-->insert into labtrans(starttime , finishtime )
values( '08:02 Am','08:42 Am'),
( '07:02 Am','08:42 Am'),
( '01:02 pm','09:02 PM'),
( '06:02 Am','08:00 Am')

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please, provide an example with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` commands with some sample data for your `starttime` and `finishtime` columns. Provide the desired result on this sample data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subtract `TIME` columns in Db2, there result is DEC(6,0) in the following format: `HHMMSS` (time duration).
See the [Time arithmetic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html) topic for details.
So, if you need to express `time duration` in the `HH+MM/60` format, then you may use the following:

```
select 
  starttime, finishtime
, finishtime-starttime hhmmss
, int(finishtime-starttime)/10000
+ dec(mod((finishtime-starttime)/100, 100), 27)/60 as "hh+mm/60"
from labtrans
```

The result is:

```
STARTTIME   FINISHTIME  HHMMSS   hh+mm/60
---------   ----------  ------   --------
08:02:00    08:42:00      4000     0.6666
07:02:00    08:42:00     14000     1.6666
13:02:00    21:02:00     80000     8.0000
06:02:00    08:00:00     15800     1.9666
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help at all?

```
values hour(current time) + .01 * minute(current time)
```

returns

```
1               
----------------
           10.14

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for replay.but i want to subtract starttime  and finish time .